# Bollinger band create a alert

Tags: pine-script

I have to add a alert when the candle go outside the 2 bands (upper or lower)

I have try somes options on the alert of bollinger bands script but don't work.

I have check cross, cross under, cross over and nothing appends.  No alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get an alert once the price crosses upper or lower Bollinger Band. So:

- Your "condition" should be same as your pair. That way, the current price will be taken into consideration
- Then select the crossing type you want (crossing, crossing up, crossing down etc.)
- After that, you should select the Bollinger Band indicator because you want the price to cross the Bollinger bands
- Select the Bollinger band (upper, basis, lower)
- Make sure the option is not "only once"
- Make sure the expiration time is not soon

These settings should do what you want.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your anwser.
The problem is the value.

I need a alert for long time and any condition.  When the candle croos, then alert and not just with a value condition.

Thanks

Comment: Please see my edit (complete new answer now).

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.  Have a good day